# Does VSCode Jupyter extension have a 'jump to section' feature?

Tags: jupyter, vscode-extensions

Recently VSCode Jupyter extension has a `sticky notes` feature.
While it is cool, I thought that a 'jump to section' feature that can be activated from the Command Palette would be more productive, since people may not need to just to the parent sections all the time but actually between sibling sections or even between sections not directly related.

I tried looking for this, but the closest I can find is to navigate to the `Outline` first and then typing the starting characters of the target section.